# How to write a LINQ statement to get files with specific extensions from a dynamic list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of dynamic objects

```
List<dynamic> myDynamicList;
```

where one item would look similar to below:

```
dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
d.FileName = "SomeLibrary.dll";
d.ClientCode = "XX";
```

If I want to get all files whose extensions are .dll, I would use LINQ as follows:

```
var libraries = myDynamicList.Where(d => Path.GetExtension(d.FileName) == ".dll")
                             .Select(d => d.FileName);
```

However, what I really want to do is get all files whose extensions are **.dll** or **.exe**. I don't want to use OR logic on the FileName because I would like to define the extensions in a list or an array. How would I accomplish that with LINQ?

Comment: You have several pieces to your puzzle, so it's not entirely clear what you want or what the problem is.  You say you have a dynamic "list" but only show one object.  You mention using a config file but don;t show any effort trying to read from it.  You mention using dynamic for some reason when you seem to know the structure ahead of time.  Where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: @DStanley I updated the question to try to alleviate any confusion. I added the definition of the list of dynamic objects and removed any references to the config since I know how to implement that piece. octavioccl provided the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a list to save all the extension that you need and use [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method in your query:

```
var list=new List<string>(){".dll", ".exe"};
var libraries = myDynamicList.Where(d => list.Contains(Path.GetExtension(d.FileName)))
                             .Select(d => d.FileName);
```

You can also use [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method:

```
 var libraries = myDynamicList.Where(d => list.Any(e=>e==Path.GetExtension(d.FileName)))
                              .Select(d => d.FileName);
```

Comment: Alternatively, in just one line: `myDynamicList.Where(d => new[] { ".dll", ".exe" }.Any(e => e == Path.GetExtension(d.FileName))).Select(d => d.FileName);`

Comment: Agreed with @MatiasCicero. I suggested the list outside in case the OP need to add/remove values from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
web.config


<configuration>
   ....
   <appSettings>
      <add key="ExtensionArray" value="dll,exe"/>
   </appSettings>
   ....
</configuration>


C# snippet

string ExtensionArray== WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Extension"];

var list=ExtensionArray.Split(',').ToList<string>();

var libraries = myDynamicList.Where(d => list.Any(e=>e==Path.GetExtension(d.FileName)))
                              .Select(d => d.FileName);
```