# How to extract the substring within the element of an array

Tags: c#

I am creating a photo and video viewer in which each one has an array with the elements that are going to be inserted and I want to filter its format to store them in a third list

I had a player where one had a array and an intercommunication for photos and videos, then only in the photo section you could only add photos and in the videos you could only add videos, then what I want to do is that in a third array I add either Photo or video and filtering them looking for the extension of the file to add them to their corresponding array.

insert files without a specific order:

```
string fileList = { "Animals.jpg", "cars.mp4", "planes.mp4", "landscape.jpg", "gameplay.mp4", "freind.mp4", "grildfriend.jpg", "travel.mp4", "school.jpg", "youtube.mp4", "asdada.jpg"};
```

and then it will be like that:

```
string PhotoList[] = { "Animals.jpg", "landscape.jpg", "grildfriend.jpg", "school.jpg","asdada.jpg" };
string VideoList[] = { "cars.mp4", "planes.mp4", "gameplay.mp4" "freind.mp4", "travel.mp4", "youtube.mp4" };
```

so far I can only concatenate the two array in a array but this keeps the order of the previous two

Comment: None of the code you posted compiles...

Comment: First you need to use a `for` loop to iterate over the `fileList` array. Then you need to look at the documentation for `string` to find a function to get the characters at the end.

Comment: Your code does not compile (however the reason for this is obvious) and you don't post any attempt to solve the question. If you are developing a media player, sorting file name according their extensions is something incredibly simple.

Comment: You probably want to use a List/ ArrayList since the array size would be dynamic.
I'd do something like this:
```
    string[] fileList = new string[]{"pic.jpg","pic2.jpg","movie.mp4"};
    string filter = ".jpg"
    List<string> filteredList = new List<string>();
    for(int j=0;j<fileList.Length;j++){
        if(fileList[j].Substring(fileList[j].LastIndexOf("."))==filter){
            filteredList.Add(fileList[j]);
        }
    }
```
filteredList will now contain all the file names that end in ".jpg". You can access the list the same way you can an array.

Answer (score 0):

if your first line is an array of strings the following should work to query your array into two different arrays. You will need to add a using statement for System.Linq as well.

```cs
var pictures = fileList.Where(p => p.IndexOf(".jpg") > 0);
var videos = fileList.Where(v => v.IndexOf(".mp4") > 0);
```

Comment: Please use proper methods to deal with file names/extensions - `Path.GetExtension` in particular (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003555/c-sharp-how-to-extract-the-file-name-and-extension-from-a-path covers all of them if you need link)

Comment: What if you have file `File.jpg.mp4` :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var photoExt = new HashSet<string>{".jpg"};
var videoExt = new HashSet<string>{".mp4"};

string[] fileList = new [] { "Animals.jpg", "cars.mp4", 
        "planes.mp4", "landscape.jpg", 
        "gameplay.mp4", "freind.mp4", 
        "grildfriend.jpg", "travel.mp4", 
        "school.jpg", "youtube.mp4", "asdada.jpg"};

string[] photos = fileList.Where(f => photoExt.Contains(Path.GetExtension(f))).ToArray();
string[] videos = fileList.Where(f => videoExt.Contains(Path.GetExtension(f))).ToArray();
```

Comment: Since code is essentially the same as [suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36138402/477420) consider at least explaining why yours better (like "HashSet of one element is far superior to Contains on array of one element")

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Didn't check duplicates at all :). Of couse, it is not superior(for small num of element) it is just the first option always if you need the search O(1)...